# Javascript/jQuery elements not working until page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a strange problem where the javascript/jQuery on my homepage is only working after I reload the page. Both the floating menu and smooth scroll fail to work as expected. The problem can be replicated by forcing the browser to get a new version of the page (ie, Ctrl+F5).

I include the code below. The first bit is the floating menu, and the second is the smooth scroll.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function UpdateTableHeaders() {
   $(".persist-area").each(function() {

       var el             = $(this),
           offset         = el.offset(),
           scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop(),
           floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this)

       if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.height())) {
           floatingHeader.css({
            "visibility": "visible"
           });
       } else {
           floatingHeader.css({
            "visibility": "hidden"
           });      
       };
   });
}

// DOM Ready      
$(function() {

   var clonedHeaderRow;

   $(".persist-area").each(function() {
       clonedHeaderRow = $(".persist-header", this);
       clonedHeaderRow
         .before(clonedHeaderRow.clone())
         .css("width", '100%')
         .addClass("floatingHeader");

   });

   $(window)
    .scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
    .trigger("scroll");

});
</script>

<script>
    $(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[id=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top - 40
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

I have a sneaking suspicion that the problem might be a change I made to the floating menu where I set the width to 100% rather than finding the parent width (which then gave a width in pixels) because the element was full width anyway, and when the page is viewed on a mobile the floating menu wasn't updating to the new width when the device orientation changed.

If that is the problem, is there a better way to update the width of the menu on orientation change instead?

I know that's quite a lot to go on there!

Comment: If a refresh solves the problem, it's usually due to browser caching an old version of the script.

Comment: Other possibilities would be due to incorrect use of cookies or localStorage, because those are the only things that persist across reloads of the page. But your code doesn't use either of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I might of solved it.

Where I commented `// DOM ready` I didn't actually wrap it in a `$( document ).ready(function()` function. I have now, and it seems to have solved the problem.

Schoolboy error 101!